# run executable from makefile with cgreen

Tags: linux, unit-testing, makefile, command-line, executable

compiling unit tests with cgreen works with a makefile. But running the exe from the makefile explicitly only works when there are passing tests. Here's my makefile:

```
1
2  ## 2020-July-01
3
4  CC=gcc
5
6  .PHONY: Etarget
7  Etarget: hello
8
9  hello:
10    -$(CC) -c hello.c
11    -$(CC) hello.o  -o hello -lcgreen
12    -echo
13    -./hello
```

and here hello.c:

```
#include <cgreen/cgreen.h>

Describe(Cgreen);
BeforeEach(Cgreen){}
AfterEach(Cgreen){}

Ensure(Cgreen, passes_this_test) {
    assert_that( 1 == 1);
}

Ensure(Cgreen, fails_this_test) {
    assert_that( 0 == 1 );
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    TestSuite *suite = create_test_suite();
    add_test_with_context(suite, Cgreen, passes_this_test);
    add_test_with_context(suite, Cgreen, fails_this_test);
    return run_test_suite(suite, create_text_reporter());
}
```

The assert "fails_this_test" leads to this error:

```
makefile:10: recipe for target 'hello' failed
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

Is there a way around this?
I'm just wondering because I can run the following code sequentially without errors. I just can't pack it into a makefile.

```
gcc -c hello.c
gcc hello.o -o hello -lcgreen
./hello
```

The output of ./hello already sufficiently informs me of the test results:

```
Running "main" (2 tests)...
hello.c:12: Failure: fails_this_test 
    Expected [0 == 1] to [be true]

  "main": 1 pass, 1 failure in 1ms.
Completed "main": 1 pass, 1 failure in 1ms.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't actually show us what your makefile says at line 10 so we can only guess.

However, make intentionally checks whether the command you give it succeeded or failed (by looking at the exit code).  That's how it knows to stop building things if you have a compile error for example.  Make has no idea that the thing you want it to do might be expected to fail, unless you tell it.

You can do that in various ways: one way is by prefixing the recipe with a `-` character.  See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html) for details.

However, I'm not sure I understand what you want.  If your test fails, why *wouldn't* you want make to exit with an error?  How else would you know that something failed?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've mistaken the make cmd for a simple script. It makes sense to stop there.